# How to fetch entire record if match is found in csv file

Tags: linux, shell, csv

I want to fetch a record from csv file if match is found.

**Sample data:**

```
"ID","NAME","CITY"
"001","A1","B1"
"001","A2","B2"
"001","A3","B3"
"001","A1","B1"
"001","A1","B1"
"001","A1","B1"
```

When I grep a keyword like "A1" then all record which as A1 should be displayed as output.

**Output:**

```
"ID","NAME","CITY"
"001","A1","B1"
"001","A1","B1"
"001","A1","B1"
"001","A1","B1"
```

**My command not working:**

```
grep "A1" demo.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$ egrep "A1|NAME" demo.csv 
"ID","NAME","CITY"
"001","A1","B1"
"001","A1","B1"
"001","A1","B1"
"001","A1","B1"
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question please check the answers on [this question](http://%20https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80471/selecting-rows-in-a-csv-file-based-on-column-value)

The above link might be helpful.

Apart from that, I looped over the excel sheet in python using the [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

I fetched rows by iterating over the excel sheet (Pandas can work with CSVs as well).

I used following code:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('Path of xlsx') #   

df = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns= [<Name of Columns>])

pd.DataFrame(df1,columns['From','To'])

for i in range(len(df)): 
from_postal_code = df.loc[i, "From"]
to_postal_code = df.loc[i, "To"]
print(from_postal_code)
print(to_postal_code)
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `csvgrep` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (Always a good idea to use a tool that understands a structured format over something generic when possible):

```
$ csvgrep -c 2 -m A1 demo.csv
ID,NAME,CITY
001,A1,B1
001,A1,B1
001,A1,B1
001,A1,B1
```